# What ways can we get around the effects of microgravity?

Tags: gravity, microgravity

One of the main factors limiting manned space exploration is the effects of living in zero-gravity on a long term basis. Aside from planting a big lump of rock beneath a starship or using a centrifuge (Like Interstellar), what other ways could a permanent crew get around the effects of microgravity?

My first thought was that (Assuming we could do it), some kind of cryogenics would serve well to stop nonessential crew (Ex. Soldiers, scientists, colonists) from experiencing bone warping and muscle deterioration (Though this isn't verified at all, but my own thoughts)

Without creating or creating the effects of gravity, how can we get around the problems of microgravity  for if/ when we start exploring in manned craft?

Comment: This is actually pretty broad the way you ask it, because there's simply many different adverse effects of prolonged stay in microgravity on the human body and even more possible ways of mitigating or alleviating them, from prevention to symptomatic treatments as problems start developing. But you also specifically ask about the possibility of cryogenic suspension (cryopreservation), so I'd suggest that you [edit] your question to focus on that and make it more specific. For the rest, see questions tagged as [tag:microgravity], perhaps combined with [tag:health] or [tag:medical]. Thanks!

Comment: We could stay on Earth. If that has high enough technology readiness level.

Comment: Living aboard Mir/ISS seems to be possible for long continuous duration ([8 months or more](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_spaceflight_records#Most_time_in_space)), albeit some effects, including post-flight, must be accepted. This won't allow interstellar, but when interstellar travel will be considered in practical, we may expect micro-gravity will not be a problem either (maybe we'll grow children in microgravity to have them ready for expeditions, Brave New World). What is the duration you're looking for?

Comment: You simply spin your vessel or habitat.  See e.g. '50s SF with rotating 'wheel' space stations.

Comment: You are basing your question on science that doesn't exist. [Cryonics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryonics) is the field, but it is very far from success. Freezing people is one thing, successfully reviving them is another. Rotating a craft is by far the simplest answer. By the way, are you aware of the [Worldbuilding](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/) site? If you want to look into the far future, for the purpose of a work of art, disciplined speculation is best done there. This site is hard science.

Answer (score 1):

The "easiest" solution is to develop a space drive capable of continuous 1g acceleration. Accelerate for half the trip, flip the drive around and decelerate for the second half.

Easier said then done.  There would be two obvious problems:

1. Acceleration and deceleration at that level would require literally astronomical amounts of energy especially as you reached the speed of light.
2. The speed of light remains a barrier. Acceleration at 10 m/s^2 would reach light speed within a year.

Comment: I happened to calculate the distance travelled, and it came out to be 30,650 AU to accelerate to c, and another 30,650 AU to decelerate to 0 using acceleration equal to 9.8 m/s$^2$.